# Subject-verb inversion

Tags: verbs, inversion, subjects

I've seen these sentences :

> There goes the train!
>
> There goes Peter!
>
> Here comes Peter!

But

> There he goes!
>
> Here he comes!

Why is there a **subject-verb inversion** when the subject is not a personal pronoun? Is there any grammatical rule?

Comment: They are not subject-verb inversions but a special kind of subject-dependent inversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subject inversion can happen following "here" and "there", when these words are function as adverbs of place, and the subject isn't a pronoun.

So yes, there is a grammatical rule.

More generally with adverbs of location and not a "weak" pronoun, inversion is possible.

> Here's your coffee.
>
> but: Here it is.
>
> On the table lay a book
>
> Round the rugged rock ran the ragged ruffian

Wikipedia has https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English#Locative_inversion and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V2_word_order

Answer (score 0):

> *There goes the train!*
>
> *There goes Peter!*
>
> *Here comes Peter!*
>
> *There he goes!*
>
> *Here he comes!*

Syntactically, these are all subject-dependent inversions.

They are comparable to running commentaries describing a situation that is taking place as they are uttered.

A personal pronoun subject precedes the verb, as the last two show.